# AngularJS directive is adding an extra whitespace character, how can I remove it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

You can see the problem at [this page I am developing.](http://classroom.koipun.com/reader) It occurs after the characters 勝 and 生. I don't understand where this extra space character is coming from or how to eliminate it. Any help is appreciated.

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module("readerApp", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);


app.controller('ReaderCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.knownKanji = 0;
    $scope.definition = "";

    $scope.dictionary = {
        '生きる': {
            meaning: 'To live',
            sample: '生きる意味を教えてくれ。',
            kanji: {
                '生' : 'live'
            }
        },
        '勝つ': {
            meaning: 'To win',
            sample: '明日は勝てないかもしれない。',
            kanji: {
                '勝': 'win'
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.$on('kanjiUp', function(event, data) {
        $scope.knownKanji += 1;
    });

    $scope.$on('kanjiDown', function(event, data) {
        $scope.knownKanji -= 1;
    });

    $scope.$on('setDefinition', function(event, data) {
        $scope.definition = $scope.dictionary[data];
        console.log($scope.definition);
    });

}).directive('kanji', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'static/js/kanji.html',
        scope: true,
        controller: function($scope, $transclude, $element) {
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            scope.reading = attrs['reading'];

            var clickingCallback = function() {
                if (scope.reading=='') {
                    scope.reading = attrs['reading'];
                    scope.$emit('kanjiDown');
                }
                else {
                    scope.reading='';
                    scope.$emit('kanjiUp');
                }
                scope.$apply();
            };
            element.bind('click', clickingCallback);
        }
    };
}).directive('line', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'static/js/line.html',
        controller: function($scope, $transclude, $element) {
            $scope.isCollapsed = true;
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            scope.translation = attrs['translation'];
        }
    };
}).directive('word', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'static/js/word.html',
        controller: function($scope, $transclude, $element) {

        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                var el = element.clone();
                var elementClone = el[0];
                el.find('rt').remove();
                var word = el.text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
                scope.$emit('setDefinition', word);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

line.html

```
<div class="line">
    <p>
        <span ng-transclude></span>
    </p>
    <i class="glyphicon"
       ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
       ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': !isCollapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': isCollapsed}">
        翻訳
    </i>
    <div uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
            <div class="well well-sm">{{translation}}</div>
    </div>
```

word.html

```
<span ng-transclude></span>
```

kanji.html

```
<ruby><span ng-transclude></span><rt>{{reading}}</rt></ruby>
```

Comment: If we don't have the directive code, how can we help you?

Comment: what does the `ruby` directive look like? it is adding an additional span and breaking the word up.

Comment: @Claies Ruby is not a directive, it is an html tag.

Comment: if you look at the html, the `ruby` element inside the `kanji` element is smaller by `8.66` pixels.  this is probably due to the fact that `kanji` is a wrapper around `ruby`;  either way, the answer @DevDig gave is a valid solution, though the problem is the nested elements, not the font, which is likely why it was given a poor response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the linked page, there is no extra space character. <strike>The visible gap is created by the used font. You might try a CSS rule to get rid of the extra space,
`kanji {margin-right: -12px;}` for example.</strike>.

As @Claies pointed out in the comments, the extra space is produced by the `span` element of the directive. The directive needs to be cofigured with `replace: true` to remove the directive element.
See [the AngularJS documentation for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) for details.

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, since it does provide a proper answer.  the `kanji` directive does indeed introduce an additional `span` which makes the element wider than the single character contained inside;  setting the margin to compensate is a valid solution.

Comment: @Claies Do you know a way the transclusion could be made without the extra span?

Comment: @tatsuhirosatou Did you try adding `replace: true` to your directive to get rid of the enclosing element?

Comment: @DevDig that solved it! Thanks! If you create your own answer I will mark it as solved.